# Attempting to send video on WhatsApp causes crash

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, whatsapp.app

I've tried a bunch of different things but whenever I try to send a video on WhatsApp the app crashes. It works fine in safe mode though.

Any ideas?

http://pastebin.com/brjzVrBS

PS: I jailbroke the phone

Comment: Could you expand on *what* different things you've tried?

Comment: I've tried a lot of dif things, deleting and reinstalling, restarting, deleting every recent cydia tweak.  I thought maybe there was something in the crash log that I was just plain missing.  Gonna resintall cydia and remove every single addition one by one once I get home.  See if any is doing it.

Comment: I had the same problem too but the file that I deleted was titled systemasm.dylib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through your log I noticed a library called `Unflod.dylib`.

This is malware. You might want to remove it ASAP.

http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/04/21/new-ios-malware-with-a-funky-name-unflod-baby-panda/

Users on Reddit are suggesting it grabs your Apple ID and password and sends it to a server in China. So you might want to reset the password for your Apple ID too.

http://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/23bdwr/beware_unfloddylib_sends_apple_id_and_password_to/

BTW At least one user on Reddit says it made their WhatsApp crash too. So removing this might stop the WhatsApp crashes.
http://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/23b7qs/what_is_unflod_its_a_mobile_substrate_addon_that/cgve5aq

Comment: Woot!  You're a lifesaver.  Deleted it with ifile and everything works now.  I was about to just restore everything...  Changed my passwords too.  Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

For application specific issues like this one it's usually a good approach to look for similar issues on the vendor [website](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/) or to contact the vendor directly (see http://www.whatsapp.com/contact/).

Also, basic things you might try (and maybe have already done) include

- restart your iPhone
- try to send a different video or a photo
- backup your old chats, delete WhatsApp, restart your iPhone and reinstall WhatsApp again

Comment: Whatsapps answer to anything is "we don't help jailbroken phones".  It's their policy.  To be more precise only videos don't work.  Pictures work fine.  Any video.

Comment: Also already tried resintalling.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have MobileSubstrate installed. Try restarting Springboard in Safe Mode, which disables all your Cydia installed apps and see if WhatsApp still crashes. This'll at least prove whether it is something installed from Cydia that is causing the crashes.

Install Safe Mode Launcher from Cydia. It'll give you the option to restart Springboard in Safe Mode.

Comment: OP has already noted that 'it works fine in safe mode'

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.